# Gatling setting OK or KO in asynchronous processing

Tags: java, performance-testing, gatling

We are using Gatling framework to run performance test on our micro services. All our micro services are backend ones and integrates between them either via JMS or Kafka. Usually a message enters one of our micro-services either as an API call or as a JMS message or as a Kafka record and exits either as an API call or JMS message or as Kafka record.

To be able to support our testing we built some in house custom actions implementing `io.gatling.core.action.ChainableAction` and `com.typesafe.scalalogging.StrictLogging` interfaces. These actions are base on the input and the output on some micro service so we ended up with some `HttpToKafkaAction`, `HttpToJmsAction`, `KafkaToJmsAction` and so on.

The way these actions work is by initiating a request and asynchronously waiting for the output to arrive. If the output is produced within less than a timeout period we mark the execution as `OK`, if the output does not pops up within this timeout period we mark the execution as `KO`.

This looked all right at a very first look but we started noticing false negatives (false `KO`s) when it took the application close to nothing to process a message (request) but gatling did not get the output within the timeout period. **This highlighted a major design issue because the time taking gatling to get the response should have nothing to do with when the processing started and ended.**

During test execution there are output listeners (Kafka, or MQ) that will keep getting the outputs and record the end times together with the start time in some `key, startTime, endTime` structure. So at this point we could know accurately whether the message was processed within the expected time or not.
The issue is that these listeners are totally decoupled from the asynchronous process waiting for these structure to be populated and if not populated it will timeout. In other words at the moment output arrived the message is already marked as timeout.

What we like is to have the possibility to decouple input producing from output receiving and take the decision of whether it was in time or not based on the start time and end time rather than how long we waited for the output.

Hope I managed to make myself clear and open to suggestions about how to achieve this. Gatling is a performance framework enforced to use at enterprise level. It would take us a small effort to implement what we want without Gatling but this is not an option. Also Gatling execution reports look nice and easy to read so somehow hard to give up on them.

Comment: Sorry, but it's unclear what you're asking for. From my understanding, there's a design issue with your in-house extension and the way you register your listeners and the way you correlate events. You're maybe looking for consulting.

Comment: I am an ordinary developer and have no financial decisions power. What I am after is to find out if there is a way to postpone in a `Gating` scenario the decision if OK or KO until the moment we know for sure it was an OK or a KO. Hope it brings some clarifications

Comment: "find out if there is a way to postpone in a Gating scenario the decision if OK or KO". No. You must define the status when you're logging the "response" event.

Comment: Hmmm This is what I thought too, unfortunately. Tell me pls, is there a way to delay the performance run finish for a given period of time (configurable) after the injection is done?

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm the creator of Gatling and the CTO of the company. My understanding is that you have to build a complex system coordinating asynchronous events from multiple sources. This is a complex task that requires time to collect private information about your system and then design. I can only help with this through corporate consulting under NDA. Your managers can reach out here if interested: https://gatling.io/contact/. Regards.